# limits of valgrind on FreeBSD

Tags: valgrind, freebsd

I have been attempting to find some suspected memory errors using valgrind.

Before the program being profiled even reaches the point I wish to profile, it bails as calls to mmap start failing. These calls succeed when it is not under valgrind.

Is there some kind of limit on the number of file mappings / mapped memory that is possible under valgrind ?

The size of files being mapped is large (around 600Gb total)

Comment: can you valgrind the program in sections? or `#if 0` sections to try to isolate where the leaks are?

Comment: not easily. And I may / am probably trying to find a leak caused by logic thats activated above a high threshold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, valgrind does not support so much memory.
On linux, the default (hardcoded in the sources) is 128 GB.

Note that the memory was increased from 64GB to 128 GB in commit
e706fbfa9fa563e81d6dc09de2bf785b2c34e84e.

The changes in this commit will point at the needed changes to further
increase the max memory supported by valgrind.

The file coregrind/m_aspacemgr/aspacemgr-linux.c contains comments explaining
the strategy to manage the memory and the mappings.
This indicates that possibly a fixed mapping of a size bigger that 128GB
might be accepted, if you mmap it above the (current linux) 128 GB limit.
(I have not tried this so this needs confirmation).

There are also other hardcoded maxima, e.g. the max nr of segments
is defined (on linux) to be 30000 in aspacemgr-linux.c.

Comment: And it gets roughly twice as far through trying to map things running on a linux machine than it does on a bsd machine. This seems to also apply to named as well as anonymous mappings, which is not the way I read the comments in aspacemgr-linux.c So there is no way round this short of building oneself modifying these values?

Comment: Possibly bsd valgrind is still based on the valgrind version that had 64GB as max.  I need to re-read the comments in aspacemgr-linux.c, as I understood *fixed* mappings could go over 128 GB: "   Note that the aspacem_minAddr/aspacem_maxAddr limits apply only to
   anonymous mappings.  The client can still do fixed and hinted maps
   at any addresses ..." .  In any case, if that does not work, the only way to have valgrind allowing more memory is effectively to modify the code.

Comment: That said, a mapped file with 'MAP_SHARED' is neither fixed, nor anonymous. but this limit certainly seems to apply in this case

Answer (score 1):

The current limits (Dec 2022) for 64 bit systems are:

macOS
aspacem_maxAddr = (Addr) 0x7fffffffffff;
That's 128TB though I rather doubt it works

FreeBSD
aspacem_maxAddr = (Addr) (Addr)0x800000000UL - 1; // 32G

Solaris and Linux
aspacem_maxAddr = (Addr)0x2000000000ULL - 1; // 128G

The limits are lower, obviously, for 32bit versions and also for special builds for running Valgrind in Valgrind.

I'll see if increasing the FreeBSD limit to also be 128GB causes any problems.

EDIT:
The limit for FreeBSD amd64 is now also 128GB.