# Valgrind massif maximum mmap size

Tags: c, valgrind, mmap, large-files

When I use mmaping for a large file(80-150 GB) valgrind failed with the error `(mmap): Invalid argument`, intuitively, I realized that the problem was probably with the file size, I tried to reduce the file size by half and it worked.
The question is, how to make mmaping in Valgrind "unlimited"?

Some details:

```
System details:    ubuntu 20.04, x86, valgrind 3.21, 8 GB RAM, 2 CPU
Command:           valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=yes ./app
mmap call:         ptr = mmap(nullptr, len, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
working mmap call: ptr = mmap(nullptr, len/2, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Comment: Just to confirm, when you run the app without valgrind, does it succeed in mapping `len` bytes?

Comment: Second, you are on a 64-bit system, I hope?  And `len` is an appropriate 64-bit type, which you're certain did not overflow when you computed it?

Comment: 1) Yes, without valgrind the app works, it's a large and well maintained app
2) Yes, 64 bit. len is 80-150 GB, I suppose the appropriate size for correct work is 64 GB (but why - it's not clear to me why such a limit was set, when real mmap works with large sizes)

Comment: Does it also work if you remove ‘pages as heap’?

Comment: @PaulFloyd it basically always crashes with Valgrind with the same error

Comment: I found the post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815026/limits-of-valgrind-on-freebsd but it didn't help, in the sense that despite the constant 128 in that commit, the limit is still 64